# How to do a search function using JavaScript that searches through an XML file?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am trying to utilize a JavaScript function through a HTML page that searches through an XML file, gets a products information by it's attribute value, and then displays all information on that product on the HTML page. I have created the search bar and section where the results will be displayed, and I have the XML file done too. The problem is the JavaScript, I am unsure how to implement this function correctly and have tried several methods to no avail.

The attribute value I want to use in order to search for the file is the product code, see below for example "product code = 001-01", I would like to be able to put only the "001-01" in the search bar I've created and the page return all information for that product using JavaScript. I would also like the page to display if the product code does not exist, but this is not *absolutely* necessary.

Preferably I would just want to do this using JavaScript, XSLT, XML and HTML - not AJAX or JQuery unless it is absolutely necessary for this but I don't know for sure myself. Apologies for any trouble in advance and thank you for any suggestions, they are very much appreciated.

**XML**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "digitechProducts.xsl"?>
<productList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="digitechProducts.xsd">
   <product code="001-01">
      <productCategory>Television</productCategory>
      <productName>Samsung TE8440</productName>
      <productDescription>50" Ultra HD Crystal View, 
            Smart TV,
            4K HDR Picture,
            x4 HDMI Ports,
            x2 USB Ports,
            WiFi / Ethernet Avaialable</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>7</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>500.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="002-01">
      <productCategory>Bluetooth Speaker</productCategory>
      <productName>JBL JS7</productName>
      <productDescription>Wireless Streaming,
            20+ Hours Playtime,
            Waterproof,
            3+ Sound Inputs,
            Bass Radiator</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>9</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>180.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="003-01">
      <productCategory>Gaming Console</productCategory>
      <productName>PlayStation 4 Pro</productName>
      <productDescription>4K Gaming,
            1TB Available Storage,
            High Dynamic Range,
            Share, Connect, Play,
            Remote Play,
            Share Play</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>2</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>450.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="002-02">
      <productCategory>Bluetooth Speaker</productCategory>
      <productName>AKAL GT3303</productName>
      <productDescription>Wireless Streaming,
            200W,
            5+ Hours Playtime,
            4 Hours Charge Time,
            2+ Sound Inputs</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>19</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>125.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="004-01">
      <productCategory>Laptop</productCategory>
      <productName>Lenovo IdeaPad 01FFK</productName>
      <productDescription>Grey Colour,
            14" Screen Size,
            FHD,
            Windows 10,
            128 GB SSD</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>15</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>250.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="001-02">
      <productCategory>Television</productCategory>
      <productName>LG OO03D</productName>
      <productDescription>50" Ultra HD Crystal View,
            Smart TV ,
            4K HDR Picture,
            x4 HDMI Ports,
            x2 USB Ports,
            WiFi / Ethernet Avaialable</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>4</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>500.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="003-02">
      <productCategory>Gaming Console</productCategory>
      <productName>Xbox One S</productName>
      <productDescription>HD Gaming,
            500GB Available Storage,
            High Dynamic Range,
            Backwards Compatibility,
            Gamepass,
            Gold Membership</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>3</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>400.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="002-03">
      <productCategory>Bluetooth Speaker</productCategory>
      <productName>TOSHIBA 90112</productName>
      <productDescription>Wireless Streaming,
            150W,
            4+ Hours Playtime,
            3 Hours Charge Time,
            2+ Sound Inputs</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>14</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>75.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="005-01">
      <productCategory>Apple Technology</productCategory>
      <productName>IPad Air</productName>
      <productDescription>Rose Gold,
            64 GB Storage,
            WiFi Connectivity,
            10.9" Liquid Retina Display,
            A14 Bionic Chip</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>11</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>300.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="001-03">
      <productCategory>Television</productCategory>
      <productName>Samsung K01223</productName>
      <productDescription>70" Ultra HD,
            Smart TV,
            8K Picture Quality,
            x4 HDMI Ports,
            x4 USB Ports,
            WiFi / Ethernet Avaialable</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>3</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>800.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="001-04">
      <productCategory>Television</productCategory>
      <productName>Samsung 0K4440</productName>
      <productDescription>55" HD,
            Smart TV,
            1080p HD Picture,
            x2 HDMI Ports,
            x2 USB Ports,
            WiFi / Ethernet Avaialable</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>7</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>500.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="006-01">
      <productCategory>Android Technology</productCategory>
      <productName>Google Pixel 4A</productName>
      <productDescription>5.81" Display,
            6GB RAM,
            128 GB Storage,
            Full HD Resolution,
            12.2MP</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>17</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>550.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="006-02">
      <productCategory>Android Technology</productCategory>
      <productName>Samsung Galaxy Tab A8</productName>
      <productDescription>Quad Core Processor,
            32 GB Storage,
            1 Year Warranty,
            Black,
            15" Display</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>8</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>150.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="007-01">
      <productCategory>Camera</productCategory>
      <productName>Fujifilm Instax Mini 11</productName>
      <productDescription>Automatic Exposure,
            Self Portrait Mode,
            Ultimate Customization,
            Fashionable Design</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>19</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>150.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="004-02">
      <productCategory>Laptop</productCategory>
      <productName>MacBook Pro</productName>
      <productDescription>White Colour,
            18" Screen Size,
            32GB RAM,
            Macintosh OS,
            250 GB SSD</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>6</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>500.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="008-01">
      <productCategory>PC Monitor</productCategory>
      <productName>ViewSonic VG2756</productName>
      <productDescription>4K Ultra HD Display,
            27" Screen Size,
            IPS Panel Type,
            16:9 Aspect Ratio,
            5ms Response Time</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>2</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>450.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="006-03">
      <productCategory>Android Technology</productCategory>
      <productName>OnePlus 8 Pro</productName>
      <productDescription>120HZ Fluid Display,
            8GB RAM,
            256 GB Storage,
            Full HD Resolution,
            48 MP Quad</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>12</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>200.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="008-02">
      <productCategory>PC Monitor</productCategory>
      <productName>ASUS P9220</productName>
      <productDescription>1080p HD Display,
            28" Screen Size,
            IPS Panel Type,
            16:9 Aspect Ratio,
            6ms Response Time</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>4</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>400.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="003-03">
      <productCategory>Gaming Console</productCategory>
      <productName>Nintendo Switch</productName>
      <productDescription>Hybrid Console,
            32 GB Available Storage,
            Joy-Con Controllers,
            Surround Sound,
            Play With Friends</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>18</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>350.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
   <product code="008-03">
      <productCategory>PC Monitor</productCategory>
      <productName>LG J890KD</productName>
      <productDescription>4K Ultra HD Display,
            28" Screen Size,
            IPS Panel Type,
            16:9 Aspect Ratio,
            2ms Response Time</productDescription>
      <stockQuantity>5</stockQuantity>
      <unitPrice>600.00</unitPrice>
   </product>
</productList>
```

```html
*HTML*

<html>
   <head>
      <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Syncopate:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <title> DigiTech - Search  </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/search.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class = "header">
         <div class = "inner_header">
            <a href = "index.html">
               <div class = "logo_container">
                  <h1> DigiTech </h1>
               </div>
            </a>
            <ul class = "navigation">
               <a href = "index.html">
                  <li> Home </li>
               </a>
               <a href = "products.html">
                  <li>Products </li>
               </a>
               <a href = "search.html" class = "currentLink">
                  <li> Search </li>
               </a>
               <a href = "mission.html">
                  <li> Our Mission </li>
               </a>
               <a href="about.html">
                  <li> About Us </li>
               </a>
               <a href="contact.html">
                  <li> Contact Us </li>
               </a>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "body">
         <h1 id = "searchProd"> Search Products </h1>
         <label for = "searchText"> To find specific product information, please enter a Product Code (e.g : 004-01) : </label>
         <input type = "text" id = "searchText" name = "searchBar" required size = "10" placeholder = "Input values here...">
         <button id = "searchButton" type = "button" > Go! </button>
         <p id = "result"> Results : </p>
         <h2 id = "sampleQueries"> Sample Queries </h2>
         <br>
         <div class = "query1">
            <h2> All Products </h2>
            <p> Samsung TE8440 </p>
            <p> JBL JS7 </p>
            <p> PlayStation 4 Pro </p>
            <p> AKAL GT3303 </p>
            <p> Lenovo IdeaPad 01FFK </p>
            <p> LG OO03D </p>
            <p> Xbox One S </p>
            <p> TOSHIBA 90112 </p>
            <p> IPad Air </p>
            <p> Samsung K01223 </p>
            <p> Samsung 0K4440 </p>
            <p> Google Pixel 4A </p>
            <p> Samsung Galaxy Tab A8 </p>
            <p> Fujifilm Instax Mini 11 </p>
            <p> MacBook Pro </p>
            <p> ViewSonic VG2756 </p>
            <p> OnePlus 8 Pro </p>
            <p> ASUS P9220 </p>
            <p> Nintendo Switch </p>
            <p> LG J890KD </p>
            <br>
         </div>
         <div class = "query2">
            <h2> All Product Codes </h2>
            <p>001-01</p>
            <p>002-01</p>
            <p>003-01</p>
            <p>002-02</p>
            <p>004-01</p>
            <p>001-02</p>
            <p>003-02</p>
            <p>002-03</p>
            <p>005-01</p>
            <p>001-03</p>
            <p>001-04</p>
            <p>006-01</p>
            <p>006-02</p>
            <p>007-01</p>
            <p>004-02</p>
            <p>008-01</p>
            <p>006-03</p>
            <p>008-02</p>
            <p>003-03</p>
            <p>008-03</p>
            <br>
         </div>
         <div class = "query3">
            <h2> All Stock Quantities </h2>
            <p> 7 </p>
            <p> 9 </p>
            <p> 2 </p>
            <p> 19 </p>
            <p> 15 </p>
            <p> 4 </p>
            <p> 3 </p>
            <p> 14 </p>
            <p> 11 </p>
            <p> 3 </p>
            <p> 7 </p>
            <p> 17 </p>
            <p> 8 </p>
            <p> 19 </p>
            <p> 6 </p>
            <p> 2 </p>
            <p> 12 </p>
            <p> 4 </p>
            <p> 18 </p>
            <p> 5 </p>
            <br>
         </div>
         <div class = "query4">
            <h2> All Unit Prices </h2>
            <p> 500.00 </p>
            <p> 180.00 </p>
            <p> 450.00 </p>
            <p> 125.00 </p>
            <p> 250.00 </p>
            <p> 500.00 </p>
            <p> 400.00 </p>
            <p> 75.00 </p>
            <p> 300.00 </p>
            <p> 800.00 </p>
            <p> 500.00 </p>
            <p> 550.00 </p>
            <p> 150.00 </p>
            <p> 150.00 </p>
            <p> 500.00 </p>
            <p> 450.00 </p>
            <p> 200.00 </p>
            <p> 400.00 </p>
            <p> 350.00 </p>
            <p> 600.00 </p>
            <br>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
         <div class="inner-footer">
            <div class="footer-section privacypolicy">
               <a href = "privacy.html" id="btnFooter">
                  <p>Privacy Policy</p>
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-section termsandcondition">
               <a href = "termsandconditions.html" id="btnFooter">
                  <p>Terms & Conditions</p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Study: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Comment: I will look into that, thank you :)